# Hide a row is a field is empty

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix

I am having a problem. One of the field is empty in a row and I want to hide that row.

I have tried the below expressions

```
=IIF(Fields!CRM_PO_Ref.Value= "",TRUE,FALSE)

=IIF(IsNothing(Fields!CRM_PO_Ref.Value),TRUE,FALSE)
```

I added this expression by right clicking on TextBoxProperties ,under visibility and added an expression. This is not hiding a row.

Can someone help?

Thanks for all youre help

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Setting visibility of a text box only affects that text box, not the whole row.

There are several ways you might get the result you seek.

One is to use Row Visibility property. Right-click on the gray row selection box to the left of the table and choose Row Visibility. Choose the "Show or hide based on an expression" option and enter your expression.

Another approach is to use the Filters property of the Dataset or the Tablix or of the Row Group.

Right-click the Dataset and choose Dataset Properties then click the Filters option in the list. Click Add to add a new filter and enter your expression.

Select the Tablix then right-click the small gray square at the top left corner. Click Tablix Properties then click the Filters option in the list. Click Add to add a new filter and enter your expression.

Right-click the Row Group which contains the rows you want to hide using the list at the bottom of the report editor. Click Group Properties then click the Filters option in the list. Click Add to add a new filter and enter your expression.

A couple of notes about the expression. First, the expression only needs to return true or false, so putting it in an `IIF()` is sort of redundant. An expression like `=Fields!CRM_PO_Ref.Value = ""` is adequate. The second thing to note is that a `True` value for the Row Visibility feature will hide the row, while a `True` result in the Filter will cause the row to be included. You might need to invert the result of your expression by preceeding it with the `Not` keyword or by inverting the comparison operator.

Comment: Turns our, I was using the wrong options haha...Stupid of me hahaha...THANK YOUUU!!!